# Compile terminal application for Android shell to record current time?

Tags: java, android, shell, adb

The date command in epoch time mode only gives seconds resolution when called from inside adb shell on android device (e.g. `date +%s.%N` returns 14403022.N... so I can only use `date +%s`)

I need a small terminal program that I can run from adb shell to record a timestamp. I know I can use java methods such as `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()` from inside my android application to record time.... however, how can I compile a little program that I can just call from adb shell simply to record time values with either `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()`?

Comment: These related might be useful: 1) [Adding a custom tool to the android adb shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131081/adding-a-custom-tool-to-the-android-adb-shell) and 2) [How can i run C binary (executable file) in Android from Android Shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868309/how-can-i-run-c-binary-executable-file-in-android-from-android-shell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get current time with high resolution in your android shell scripts use `$EPOCHREALTIME` built-in shell variable.